# Active noise cancelling headphones with decent passive as well

Tags: headphones

I am in the market for new headphones. I currently have Sennheiser HD380 headphones.

I'd like noise cancelling. Most active noise cancelling headphones however have fairly weak passive noise cancelling. This means voices/etc come through *decently* well. I'm also fairly spoiled in overall sound quality with my current HD380.

Requirements:

- Similar sound quality to the HD380s
- Wireless
- < $350ish
- Decent active noise cancelling as well as some level of passive

Undecided requirements:

- Over-ear vs in-ear

Comment: there are some similar questions but the most recent I found was nearly 2 years ago still, so I figured this is probably ok to ask again.